# Unexpected printf() behavior in Octave for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, printf, octave, race-condition

I just recently switched from MATLAB to Octave because my license ran out and I wanted to give it a shot before renewing, so I can't check the behavior in MATLAB right now. I am not sure if I am making a grave mistake here, but I am having some headache over a for-loop in Octave.

The loop was supposed to find the first "large" change (`0.08`) in the values of one of the columns (column `5` in this case) of a [csv-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbff6dys9epxjy9/gpsdata.mat?dl=0) I previously read with `dlmread()`, and then return to me the index of the first change so I can discard all the data before this first big change occurs for my further computations.

While trying to solve this I remembered that one should avoid for-loops in MATLAB (and probably Octave as well), and I managed to get the result I want by just doing

```
idx = find(diff(gpsdata(:,5)) > 0.08, 1);
```

which is obviously much cleaner (and probably faster too?) and I will stick with it; however, I am still wondering why the for-loop is showing this weird behavior.

Is there a mistake in my code, or is that just a sign of why for-loops should be avoided in Octave/MATLAB? Are for-loops parallelized in Octave/MATLAB, is that why this is happening?

### Code

```
for (jj = 1:(size(gpsdata, 1) - 1))
  if (gpsdata(jj, 5) + 0.08 < (gpsdata(jj+1, 5)))
    idx = jj;
    disp(["jj=" num2str(jj) ", idx=" num2str(idx)]);
    printf("Found index %d, at %f s real time\n", num2str(idx), gpsdata(idx, 2));
    break;
  end
end
```

### Actual Output:

```
jj=380, idx=380
Found index 51, at 56.000000 s real time
Found index 48, at 19.770000 s real time
```

### Expected Output:

```
jj=380, idx=380
Found index 380, at 19.770000 s real time
```

The `disp()` call produced the correct output, while the `printf()` is somehow executed twice on top of returning wrong values, with only the fourth of the 4 arguments being correct (the `19.770000` is the expected output here); the other 3 values (`51`, `56.000000`, and `48`) are wrong.

### Data for Reproducing

The data I am using for `gpsdata` can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wbff6dys9epxjy9/gpsdata.mat?dl=0), and read in with `data=load("~/gpsdata.mat");` followed by `gpsdata=data.gpsdata;`.

Comment: In the `printf` call change `num2str(idx)` to `idx`.

Comment: That's it, of course. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @rahnema1, I was passing a `string` instead of an `int` by doing `printf("%d", num2str(idx))` so Octave was printing the ascii codes for `"380"`, which happen to be `51`, `56`, `48`.

Doing `printf("%d", idx)` yields the expected behavior.

Thanks for catching that!